# Blender freezes up, after hibernate while Blender is 'Not Responding'

Tags: rigid-body-simulation, windows

Sometimes when Blender is doing rigid body simulations, it says 'Not Responding' and then after a while it responds again. But when I make the computer 'hibernate', while Blender is in 'Not Responding' state and I resume the computer, then Blender freezes up and I have to close Blender and start everything all over again. What should I do next time, instead of closing Blender and start all over again?

Comment: @cegaton Should have been an answer, not a comment.

Comment: window's hibernation can screw up a lot of things, not just blender, so do *not* hibernate your computer well blender is working. Think about it, how can blender work if the computer is (nearly) off.

Comment: @David - do you have any references for this? (if its a known problem. its good to link to sources)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you know the answer to this one already. 3D can be one of the of the most computationally intensive activities to throw at a computer. It becomes unresponsive because is busy crunching the numbers to work out your simulation..... Judging by your post, you are indeed pushing your computer to it's limits. Let it do its' job... don't hibernate it... get a book, meditate, go for a walk, interact with other humans. 3D requires a bit of patience sometimes... Once blender has finished is job and your computer is back, bake the simulation and save your file so you don't have to start over

Comment: Just crunching numbers isn't likely to be the root cause - suspect its driver related (Blender use of OpenGL or audio driver). ~ You could check if other 3d or sound/video editing applications have issues with hibernate on Windows too. Seems this problem isn't unique to Blender, eg: http://www.sonycreativesoftware.com/Forums/ShowMessage.asp?Forum=4&MessageID=682411

Answer (score 0):

Like the above, but if it's regularly failing to respond during rendering, save a copy to a flash drive (and an external backup drive as well if you have a compatible one,) and *then* let it render. Just put a sticky note over it and turn the monitor off. Then go out and do something else for a while.

Comment: The reason why I say make backups is because if it's failing to respond that often, I'm starting to think the hardrive might melt and you will lose all your work.